# Populating a table from a view in Oracle with "locked" truncate/populate

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to populate a table from a (potentially large) view on a scheduled basis.

My process would be:

- Disable indexes on table
- Truncate table
- Copy data from view to table
- Enable indexes on table

In SQL Server, I can wrap the process in a transaction such that when I truncate the table a schema modification lock will be held until I commit. This effectively means that no other process can insert/update/whatever until the entire process is complete.

However I am aware that in Oracle the truncate table statement is considered DDL and will thus issue an implicit commit.

So my question is how can I mimic the behaviour of SQL Server here? I don't want any other process trying to insert/update/whatever whilst I am truncating and (re)populating the table. I would also prefer my other process to be unaware of any locks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can delete rather than truncate, but that generates more redo and takes longer, locking the table for longer - as you seem to realise. I'm wondering if you might want a materialized view here instead of the table, refreshed on a schedule? Would that fit what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As I (subtly) alluded to in my question, I have another process that will write to the table/materialized view. Can I write to a materialized view in Oracle? If so, will I be immune from unique constraint violations when both processes are operating concurrently? Thanks again.

Comment: No, I guess I assumed you meant you wanted to stop updates to the source view/tables. Why do you want to allow updates to the target table if you're going to trash and repopulate it - those manual updates would all be lost each time?

Comment: It's a strange requirement I'll admit. Some data needs to be "as live as possible", meaning I want to write individual rows to the table as I persist entities in my application (not strictly inside the same transaction, rather asynchronously in a queue). The scheduled re-population will take care of changes to foreign key referenced tables (indeed it will handle all rows regardless). If I can pull it off the illusion will be that the data is live when it isn't. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Make your table a partitioned table with a single partition and local indexes only. Then whenever you need to refresh:

- Copy data from view into a new temporary table

  ```
  CREATE TABLE tmp AS SELECT ... FROM some_view;
  ```
- Exchange the partition with the temporary table:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE some_table
  EXCHANGE PARTITION part WITH TABLE tmp
  WITHOUT VALIDATION;
  ```

The table is only locked for the duration of the partition exchange, which, without validation and global index update, should be instant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Presumably the idea here would be to obtain an exclusive lock on the table, copy data to the temporary table and then exchange the table with the temporary table. My only concern would be that, even though instant, an implicit commit would occur before the ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION, potentially allowing another process to write to the table... That said, I am not entirely sure on the likelihood of this happening or whether the consequences of this would be bad. I am also not sure on whether I want to pursue a staging/swap table scenario at the moment. Thanks again.